# Javac with --patch-module

Tags: java, javac, java-9, java-module

Here is a Javac command line with --patch-module flag (from AOSP build log):
(to make it easier to read, spaces are replaced by new line)

```
javac 
--system=none 
--patch-module=java.base=/<folder name 1>/core-all.jar 
/<folder name 2>/module-info.java
```

The only reference I can find online is the section "Patching module content" and "Compile time" of http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261, but after reading those I'm still not sure what exactly the above command does.

My guess is:

(1) Replace the corresponding contents in java.base with contents from core-all.jar (only for this javac invocation)

(2) Compile module-info.java and generate its class file as normal, during the compilation process, some referenced contents in the module java.base get overridden by contents from core-all.jar.

Basically it is a normal compilation command with some library overrides.

(1) Is my understanding right?

(2) Why is there a "="  between "--patch-module" and "java.base" instead of a space between them?

Comment: Informational JEP 293 has the guidelines for JDK command line options, that should help you with the question on allowing "=" as a separator.

Comment: The `javac -X` usage for extended options has more on `---patch-module`. JEP 261 is indeed the authoritative place for information on what patching is about. So yes, the command you have overrides and/or augments the classes in the java.base module. You should be very careful doing this as overriding core classes will likely break the JDK in ways that are really hard to diagnose.